# Is "either A and B or C and D or E and F" right?

Tags: grammar

Could I say like this:

> A boss could order his subordinate in either authority and serious way or polite and friendly way or even joking and intimate way.

By the way, should I insert an "a" before three kind ways?

Answer (score 4):

- *authority* is a noun, not an adjective. You should use the adjective "authoritative" instead.
- each "X and Y way" should be preceded by "a", as you suspected in your question.

  > A boss could order his subordinate in either **an** authoritative and serious way or **a** polite and friendly way or even **a** joking and intimate way.

When making a list of three or more things, it's typical to use commas and only a final preposition.

> A boss could order his subordinate in either an authoritative and serious way, a polite and friendly way, or even a joking and intimate way.

However, be sure to note that:

- it's not clear to me that this rule really improves readability in this case; it may be more readable (but less formal) using "... or ... or ..."
- "either" is [typically used with only two options](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/is-either-only-used-with-two-options), though it may be informally used with more
- this sentence is quite long and has a lot of many conjunctions. It's grammatically correct, but you could make it easier to read by...

  - using only one adjective per phrase

    > A boss could order his subordinate in an authoritative way, a polite way, or even a joking and intimate way.
  - setting the last phrase apart with an [em dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html) (informally written on computers as a double-dash)

    > A boss could order his subordinate in either an authoritative and serious way or a polite and friendly way -- or even in a joking and intimate way.
  - using "either in ... or in ..." to help mark the start of a new phrase

    > A boss could order his subordinate either in an authoritative and serious way, in a polite and friendly way, or even in a joking and intimate way.